# Python error — TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

```
def ones_and_tens_digit_histogram(_list):
    _list = [num%100 for num in _list]
    _hist = []
    for i in range(10):
        sum = 0
        for num in  _list:
            if( int(num/10) == i):
                sum +=1
            if(num%10 == i):
                sum +=1
        _hist.append(sum/(len(_list)*2))
    return(_hist)
print(ones_and_tens_digit_histogram([127,426,28,9,90]))
print(ones_and_tens_digit_histogram([0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765]))
```

When I ran this it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/missholmes/Downloads/homework6/fraud_detection.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/missholmes/Downloads/homework6/fraud_detection.py", line 179, in main
    histogram = ones_and_tens_digit_histogram(counts)
  File "/Users/missholmes/Downloads/homework6/fraud_detection.py", line 28, in ones_and_tens_digit_histogram
    _list = [num%100 for num in _list]
  File "/Users/missholmes/Downloads/homework6/fraud_detection.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    _list = [num%100 for num in _list]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The line 28 is:_list = [num%100 for num in _list]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The above code works for me. ` histogram = ones_and_tens_digit_histogram(counts)` is not in this code... so we won't be able to reproduce the error. I'm guessing 'counts' contains strings instead of integers

Comment: The call to `ones_and_tens_digit_histogram()` that's shown in the traceback (which is not either of the calls actually shown in your posted code) is evidently being passed a list of strings rather than numbers.  The `%` operator means something rather different on a string.

Comment: so what should I do to get everything right??

Comment: Add `print(counts)` before line 179 in `fraud_detection.py` to debug what string you passed to `ones_and_tens_digit_histogram`